# Bootstrap4 control width of inline-form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

See below for my HTML. I want to make the search bar in the top right wider, and in general just have some control over its width. I've tried messing around with the grid system as that looks like the way to go however nothing I've tried actually managed to change the width of the search bar itself.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6e0448e881.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="searchbar">
                                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get">
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <input name="q" id="qbox" data-toggle="dropdown" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"/>
                                        <div id="search_results" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="qbox">
                                            <div>a</div>
                                            <div>b</div>
                                            <div>c</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                    <li class="usericon">
                        <button class="btn" id="login_dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Log in
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="login_dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <style>
                    .searchbar .dropdown-menu {
                    left: initial;
                    }
                    div#search_results {
                    width: 100%;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the width of the form-control class

```
.form-inline .form-control{
   width:600px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Results in the following on my machine (Chrome, Arch Linux): https://imgur.com/Tm3KCaF

Comment: change .form-inline .form-control class width.. answer was updated